# Pip install qiskit: Command errored out with exit status 255:

Tags: python, pip, qiskit

I am trying to install Qiskit on elementaryOS juno running Python 3.7, using pip. I even upgraded to the latest pip.

I get the following log:

```
Building wheels for collected packages: qiskit
  Building wheel for qiskit (setup.py) ... error
  ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 255:
   command: /home/laura/.pyenv/versions/anaconda3-2019.03/bin/python -u -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'/tmp/pip-install-p35oetbg/qiskit/setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'/tmp/pip-install-p35oetbg/qiskit/setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' bdist_wheel -d /tmp/pip-wheel-2ms47shp --python-tag cp37
       cwd: /tmp/pip-install-p35oetbg/qiskit/
  Complete output (1 lines):
  running bdist_wheel
  ----------------------------------------
  ERROR: Failed building wheel for qiskit
  Running setup.py clean for qiskit
Failed to build qiskit
Installing collected packages: qiskit
  Running setup.py install for qiskit ... done
Successfully installed qiskit-0.11.0
```

Comment: It says is installed successfully. What does not work?

Comment: It says: ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 255:

  ----------------------------------------
  ERROR: Failed building wheel for qiskit
  Running setup.py clean for qiskit"

I cant seem to import the module onto pycharm...

Comment: I have been reading that. But we still don't know what is not working. There is only a message. You have not stated  if the package is malfunctioning after installation.

Answer (score 0):

This error seems to be reported by various users as per issue log in the Qiskit GitHub repository. Could you please try the following steps.

1. Install Anaconda
2. Create a python 3.7 environment: conda create --name your_env python=3.7
3. conda activate your_env
4. pip install qiskit

You can report the specific details of the issues in the following GitHub repository issue log if it is persisting after following these steps.

[Qiskit GitHub Repository Issue Log](https://github.com/Qiskit/qiskit/issues/197)